# Tiny PCB fiducials?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I'm designing a PCB with a size of 25x14 mm that will be panelized. Looking at IPC standards it seems 1 mm diameter fiducial, plus clearance and SM opening is the smallest preferred size. I have components on both sides of the PCB and the smallest are 0201 resistors and capacitors. No BGAs but some smallish QFN and DFN packages. The boards is heavily populated with no room for standard fiducials.

Would it be OK to put the fiducials on the panel frame?

Edit for future readers:
We placed fiducials on the panels and it worked without any problems. Panel size was approx. 120x120 mm

Comment: Sounds like this isn't your first PCB, so you might have a preferred supplier (or suppliers). This is most definitely a question for them; the answer depends on their processes. But assuming they are assembled panelised, I can't see a fundamental problem.

Comment: You're right. Not my first and I should contact them.

Comment: I was once super worried about fiducials and one PCBA house told me they could use small SMD pads as fiducials if necessary (i.e. if you dont have space for fiducials your pads are also probably small)

Comment: @Dejvid_no1   Great that you followed up!   Note though, 120mm x 120mm is a REALLY small 'panel'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure fiducials on the panel frame are okay as long as it is populated with the panel frame in place (obviously).

That said, I imagine that would be insufficient if there is skew that varies across a large panel which would be the advantage of having fiducials on every board.

But the more likely problem is flexibility introduced from the routing or v-grooving so the boards can be removed. Board house should know.

Comment: Could that be mitigated by having even more fiducials on the panel? Strategically placed near each single PCB? I guess the PP machince then needs to be configured to recalculate for each of them.

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 If your only goal is to keep fiducials off the final PCB, I imagine that would work. But the measures made so that boards can be removed from the panel introduce flexibility and could be a reason against doing that.

Comment: In most cases, having the fiducials on the frame should be fine. I would: 1. clear it with the assembly house before manufacturing the PCBs if possible. 2. if not possible, assemble a small batch first to test or find a different assembly house.